# Which sentence is grammatically correct? (a, the, or no article)

Tags: articles

1 Today's lecture will be one hour long, with focus on income taxation.

2 Today's lecture will be one hour long, with **a** focus on income taxation.

3 Today's lecture will be one hour long, with **the** focus on income taxation.

4 Today's lecture will be one hour long, with **its** focus on income taxation.

Comment: 2 is my first choice. focus is a countable noun, it needs an article. Since the focus has not been mentioned before, use 'a'. 4 is also ok, it just avoids the problem.

Answer (score 0):

2, 3, and 4 are grammatically correct.  The most common in this context would be 2.  4 is pretty common also.

1 is close enough that most people would not object.  Normally you would see this only with an adjective

> Today's lecture will be one hour long, with special focus on income taxation.

But I think this is short/lazy for

> Today's lecture will be one hour long, with a special focus on income taxation.

Comment: I don't think it's "lazy for" anything. *Focus* doesn't need a determiner when it's used as an uncountable noun.